# What is the Point of Initializer Delegation?

Tags: swift, initialization

I am struggling to understand what the point of the Initializer Delegation is. I am currently learning Swift from the Big Nerd Ranch book and came across the following code:

```
init (region: String, population: Int, stopLights: Int) {
    self.region = region
    self.population = population
    numberOfStoplights = stopLights
}

init (population: Int, stopLights: Int {
    self.init(region: “N/A”, population: population, stopLights: stopLights)
}
```

This is very confusing to me. If the whole point of initializing an instance is to give it a value, then why would you initialize it twice?

Answer (score 0):

The second init() is just another way to initialize the class with different parameters. In this example, if the region is unknown, you can still initialize the class with the region getting a default value of "N/A".

Comment: Not sure I understand it still. In your example, if we want to let the region be "N/A" if it happens to be unknown, then can't we just initialize it as "N/A" in the beginning?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the entire code for the class you're describing. A better example might perhaps be an initializer that accepts a database id, so within that initializer the database would be queried and the resulting region, population and stoplight information would be passed to the default initializer with those three params.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apple Developer Library:

> Initializers can call other initializers to perform part of an instance’s initialization. This process, known as initializer delegation, avoids duplicating code across multiple initializers.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID215